# Issues in hover images

Tags: html, css

How can I change this exact code to do the hovering effect on mouseover?

My html code is:

```
  <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter onmouseover="this.src='facebook-hover';" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="44" height="45" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

I dont know how to use this javascript

Pls help

Comment: You have not closed the double-quote for the alt text, maybe thats why its not working.

Comment: yes i have closed alt text,but mouseover image is not displaying

Comment: Try the one I've posted below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" onMouseOver="this.src='images/facebook-hover.png'"></img></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="44" height="45" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

As per ur wish

```
      <a href="#" id="parent1" onMouseOver="changesrc(event,'images/twitter_hover.png')"><img id="child1" src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"></img></a>  
      <a href="#" id="parent2" onMouseOver="changesrc(event,'images/facebook_hover.png')"><img id="child2"src="images/facebook.png" width="44" height="45" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook"></img></a>
      <a href="#" id="parent3" onMouseOver="changesrc(event,'images/twitter_hover.png')"><img id="child3" src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"></img></a>
      <a href="#" id="parent4" onMouseOver="changesrc(event,'images/twitter_hover.png')"><img id="child4" src="images/twitter.png" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"></img></a>
```

and use this script

```
function changesrc(event,src_path) {
var t=event.target.id;
  $('#'+t).attr('src',src_path)
 }
```

Comment: i tried its working but only mouse down its working. I need whole area of facebook.png must be mouseover effect

Comment: Cant get ur point.. I ve used only mouseover.. how could it'll work in mousedown.. Impossible... i think u r telling me do this in <a> tag ryt??

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" id="twitter_img" width="44" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" onmouseover="test()" /></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function test(){
documnet.getElementById("twitter_img").src="whatever you want to replace it with";
}
```

Comment: i tried its working but only mouse down its working. I need whole area of facebook.png must be mouseover effect

Comment: This might help-> shift the `onmouseover="test()"` from the `<img>` tag to the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a CSS with rules as:

```
a img#twitter{
   background-image: url('/images/twitter.png');
   width: 44px;
   height: 45px;
}
a img#twitter:hover{
  background-image: url('/images/twitter-hover.png');
}
```

And your HTML should be as:

```
<a href="#"><img id="twitter" src="images/twitter.png" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

Now you mentioned exact code I know. You can then use:

```
a img[src="images/twitter.png"]{
   background-image: url('/images/twitter.png');
   width: 44px;
   height: 45px;
}
a img[src="images/twitter.png"]:hover{
  background-image: url('/images/twitter-hover.png');
}
```

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html
http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/pure-css-image-hover/

Comment: @user3553281 my solution didn't work for you? It's much better to use CSS or to have Unobtrusive Javascript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Added "hover-src" attribute in img tag and  onmouseover="test(this)".

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" hover-src="images/twitter.png" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" onmouseover="test(this);" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="44" hover-src="images/facebook.png" height="45" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" onmouseover="test(this);"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" hover-src="images/twitter.png" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" onmouseover="test(this);" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="44" hover-src="images/twitter.png" height="45" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" onmouseover="test(this);" /></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function test(objImg){
      objImg.src = objImg.getAttribute("hover-src");
}
```